# emails get spam if sent via C# .net 2.0 but goes to inbox if outlook is used

Tags: .net

My emails are getting spammed if i use my own software to send them. The software is in C# (with .net framework 2.0).

If i send the same mail (will all Identical settings ie. same ip, same account, same subject and body) with the outlook it goes to inbox.

It is really becoming headache, why the mails are getting spammed only if they are sent via my application, while everything works fine with outlook.

Thanx for any kind of help...

Regards,
Shail2k4

Comment: There must be a difference between your emails.  Check the details of the mail headers - check the spam report - and then post the difference here.

Answer (score 0):

Then there is a reason your mails are being marked as spam - get hold of a copy of the spam report - if you can, and see on what grounds its being flagged - often its because its not perfectly formed.

Such as:

No mailer type
Fields in odd order
contains specific phrases
Sending server is an open relay..

Comment: Please provide some detail for how can i get hold of a copy of spam report. How can i do that?

Comment: That you need to ask of whoever does your spam blocking - there are far too many options

Comment: Thanx for your valuable reply. I got this detail from the spammed mail
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: xxx.xx.xxx.xx is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of xxx@xxx.xxx) client-ip=xxx.xx.xxx.xx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: xxx.xx.xxx.xx is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of xxx@xxx.xxx) smtp.mail=xxx@xxx.xxx